# Minimum height of bottom of industrial machine control electrical panel

Tags: electrical-panel

On an industrial machine we are building, what is the minimum height of the bottom of the electrical control panel

Thank you

Comment: Is there not a UL/IEC/... standard that governs your machinery? (UL508A or equivalent, if nothing else)

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because industrial machinery is out of scope here.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are in North America.

There is no minimum height, it can be on the floor. Operators may hate you if you make them get on their knees though. Common sense prevails.

If there is a chance of flooding, you will want it above the floodplain as well.

Comment: Crazy but true+

Comment: I once had to work on a machine where the "operator panel" was mounted 8" off of the floor, on an enclosure that was 90" high. I was cursing that designer the entire time...